# get not defined against data set returned from findAll

Tags: sequelize.js

There is strange "not defined" error when the app is referring a field `artwork` in data set returned by sequelizejs 6.x `findAll`. But the `artwork` field IS in the data set.
Here is the code:

```
            console.log("[i] in retrieveOSSUrl : ", i);
            console.log("item[i] in retrieveOSSUrl : ", items[i]); //<<===data set
            console.log("item[i].artwork in retrieveOSSUrl : ", items[i].get('artwork'));  //<<====artwork not defined
```

Here is data set `item[I]` (`artwork` is the field referred to):

```
| [i] in retrieveOSSUrl :  0
0|server  | item[i] in retrieveOSSUrl :  [
0|server  |   forsale {
0|server  |     dataValues: {
0|server  |       id: 42,
0|server  |       buyer_id: null,
0|server  |       artwork_id: 42,
0|server  |       status: 'EscrowDepositMade',
0|server  |       price: 39,
0|server  |       shipping_cost: 0,
0|server  |       shipping_method: 3,
0|server  |       transaction_closed: false,
0|server  |       seller_refund_value: 39,
0|server  |       buyer_refund_value: 0,
0|server  |       escrow_value: 39,
0|server  |       deposit_date: null,
0|server  |       buy_date: null,
0|server  |       dispute_date: null,
0|server  |       active_date: 2022-06-12T01:42:51.049Z,
0|server  |       close_date: null,
0|server  |       seller_receive_payment_date: null,
0|server  |       buyer_receive_product_date: null,
0|server  |       forsale_data: null,
0|server  |       deployed_address: '0x926BD0f4af7C8268eF1e9D967fa74f09e9D3CDd9',
0|server  |       smartcontract_name: null,
0|server  |       last_updated_by_id: 2,
0|server  |       createdAt: 2022-06-12T01:42:50.966Z,
0|server  |       updatedAt: 2022-06-12T22:13:04.038Z,
0|server  |       artwork: [artwork],
0|server  |       viewer: null
0|server  |     },
0|server  |     _previousDataValues: {
0|server  |       id: 42,
0|server  |       buyer_id: null,
0|server  |       artwork_id: 42,
0|server  |       status: 'EscrowDepositMade',
0|server  |       price: 39,
0|server  |       shipping_cost: 0,
0|server  |       shipping_method: 3,
0|server  |       transaction_closed: false,
0|server  |       seller_refund_value: 39,
0|server  |       buyer_refund_value: 0,
0|server  |       escrow_value: 39,
0|server  |       deposit_date: null,
0|server  |       buy_date: null,
0|server  |       dispute_date: null,
0|server  |       active_date: 2022-06-12T01:42:51.049Z,
0|server  |       close_date: null,
0|server  |       seller_receive_payment_date: null,
0|server  |       buyer_receive_product_date: null,
0|server  |       forsale_data: null,
0|server  |       deployed_address: '0x926BD0f4af7C82681F1e9D967fa74f09e9D3CDd9',
0|server  |       smartcontract_name: null,
0|server  |       last_updated_by_id: 2,
0|server  |       createdAt: 2022-06-12T01:42:50.966Z,
0|server  |       updatedAt: 2022-06-12T22:13:04.038Z,
0|server  |       artwork: [artwork],
0|server  |       viewer: null
0|server  |     },
0|server  |     _changed: Set(0) {},
0|server  |     _options: {
0|server  |       isNewRecord: false,
0|server  |       _schema: null,
0|server  |       _schemaDelimiter: '',
0|server  |       include: [Array],
0|server  |       includeNames: [Array],
0|server  |       includeMap: [Object],
0|server  |       includeValidated: true,
0|server  |       attributes: [Array],
0|server  |       raw: true
0|server  |     },
0|server  |     isNewRecord: false,
0|server  |     artwork: artwork {. //<<====here is artwork field
0|server  |       dataValues: [Object],
0|server  |       _previousDataValues: [Object],
0|server  |       _changed: Set(0) {},
0|server  |       _options: [Object],
0|server  |       isNewRecord: false,
0|server  |       artimages: [Array],
0|server  |       viewer: [viewer],
0|server  |       category: [category]
0|server  |     },
0|server  |     viewer: null
0|server  |   }
0|server  | ]
```

Here is the error:

> 0|server  | Error in adding URL link for OSS images :  ReferenceError: get is not function

What is wrong with `item[i].get('artwork')`?

Comment: Are you sure it should be `get(artwork)` and not `get('artwork')`?

Comment: Just tried with 'artwork' and it returns `get is not a function`. Also tried without `get` and the error is `artwork not defined`

Comment: Did you try `items[i].artwork`?

Comment: `items[I],artwork` thrower `not defined`.  same error.

Comment: The problem is caused by accidentally passing sequelizejs output in an array.